# Automate Azure publish settings retrieval with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I've created a PS script for setting up components in Azure. When the script is finished I store a bunch of variables in a config file. One of the variables I need is in the publish settings file. I've so far only found this command

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
```

But this command opens a web browser and downloads the file, that's not very easy to work with in a script. Is there some parameters you can give to this command to make it use the login done in powershell? Or maybe there is some other command that can extract this information without going through a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile**.

```
$resourceGroupName = "contoso"
$webAppName = "contoso-web"
$outfile = "C:\temp\contoso-web-pub-settings.xml"

Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $webAppName -OutputFile $outfile
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Rick. But the 'publish profile' contains credentials on how to deploy to a web app. I'm looking for the 'publish settings' file which contains credentials to the subscriptions.

Comment: My bad.  I completely misread the question.  If you need programmatic access to the credentials, then download the settings file and store the management certificate in Key Vault.